# A curious coincidence in the series representation of $\zeta(7)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

Let $\zeta(n)$ denote the Riemann Zeta function defined for positive integers $n$ as usual by:

$$
\zeta(n)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^n}.
$$

It is currently unknown whether there exists a series representation of $\zeta$ for odd integers $n>3$ of the form:

$$
\zeta (n)=\xi _{{n}}\sum _{{m=1}}^{{\infty }}{\frac  {(-1)^{{m-1}}}{m^{{n}}{\binom  {2m}{m}}}},
$$

where $\xi_n$ is an algebraic number. For instance, for the case $n=3$, we have $\xi_3=\frac{5}{2}$. If such a $\xi_n$ is found, for any odd $n>3
$, one could use Apéry's proof of the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$ to prove the irrationality of $\zeta(n)$. Despite extensive computer searching, no such $\xi_n$ was found for $n>3$ and it can be shown (1) that if one exists, then the coefficients in its minimal polynomial must be enormous.

You can imagine my surprise when I found that

$$
\xi_7 \approx \frac{\pi^7}{500^2 \sinh^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})^7},
$$

which, despite the fact that it contains a power of $\pi$, is even more surprising given its striking similarity to the well-known value for $\xi_2$:

$$
\xi_2 = \frac{\pi^2}{12 \sinh^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})^2}.
$$

I know that [seemingly remarkable mathematical
coincidences are easy to generate](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3903/cdce91c73af50b97f24e7825932139867073.pdf), however this one is far too remarkable to immediately dismiss as pure coincidence. Don't get me wrong, it is most probably a coincidence, but a beatiful one indeed.

How may one attempt to explain this coincidence? Is there a "good" reason for this, other than chance?

---

*References*

(1)  D. H. Bailey, J. Borwein, N. Calkin, R. Girgensohn, R. Luke, and V. Moll, Experimental Mathematics in Action, 2007.

Comment: Did you find this result by just guessing values and comparing numerically for a long time or this there a reason you tried this particular value?

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov Intelligent guesswork :) I was trying to find $x$ such that $\xi_n \approx \frac{\pi^n}{x \sinh^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})^n}$. No such "interesting" $x$ exists for odd $n$ except at $n=7$.

Comment: And how accurate is the approximation of $\xi_2$, and how accurate is the one of $\xi_7$?

Comment: How can you be surprised when you were specifically looking for this form ?

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov The value for $\xi_2$ is not an approximation.

Comment: Oh I misread then, sorry!

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did not expect to find the integer $x=500^2$.

Comment: How many exact digits ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: $500 \approx 500.00047054664\ldots$